# File Reader IO Reading Text Files

Tags: java, file, input, output, filereader

I have an assignment that asks me to read a code from a text file.  Does anybody know what would be wrong with my code?

*Instead of outputting the text itself it also outputs extra characters:*

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf390{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\f0\fs24 \cf0 ana\nan\stop\pots}

*when it should just be outputting this:*

ana

nan

stop

pots

*Heres the code:*

```
package anagram1;

import java.io.FileReader; //Access file systems and allows buffered reader
                        //to read
import java.io.BufferedReader; //Scanner

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagram1 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String path;
    Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter file path.");
    path = prompt.nextLine();


    FileReader file = new FileReader(path);  //here is where the file path is inserted
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);


    String text = ""; //stores what is inside file
    String line = reader.readLine(); //keeps reading line after line of string given
    while (line != null)
    {
        text += line;
        line = reader.readLine();

    }

    System.out.println(text);
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: open your file with `notepad` and see whether there are  extra chars present or not. I faced this problem yesterday and opening file in notpad solved my issue.

Comment: looks like your input file is in .rtf-format instead of .txt

Comment: You are not reading a TXT file, but a RTF file. By the way: Do not concatenate strings with the + operator. Use a StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

It seems your text file contains not only the expected four lines but other code.

**Former content**

Are you sure your text file ONLY contains these four strings and is no special format? You could probably check with another text file you freshly created.

Comment: This is more of a comment. Not an answer

Answer (score 2):

A file reader doesn't magically understands the RTF format and doesn't magically strips all the formatting markup. It reads characters from a file, without caring about what these characters represent.

You need an RTF document parser if you want to be able to do that. Or you need to make your file a pure text file, and not an RTF document.

Comment: Thanks !!  Plain text works.

one more question though.

my input text is: 

hi 


ih

snap

pans

pots


stop

but the output is run on like this:
hi ihsnappanspotsstop <--- how do breaks fit in the code?

Comment: readLine() returns the line, without its EOL character. If you want to add spacing or EOLs to your output, then append them explicitely.